# Unable to invoke the button click event when I am using document.arrive()

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, I am using this JavaScript code to invoke a button click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById('buttonId').click();
})
```

It works independently. But If I want to use this inside `document.arrive()`, something like this below, it doesn't work.

```
document.arrive("something...", function(){

  $(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('buttonId').click();
  })

})
```

How to resolve this? Any help is appreciated.

I am expecting the button click to happen once certain element is available on the page. That's why used `document.arrive()`. I have debugged and it goes inside `document.arrive()` and executes other code, but not the button click.

Comment: So you're using the "arrive.js" library?

Comment: If you are usnig that library, then it's almost completely redundant. Use event delegation instead.

Comment: Try removing the `$(document).ready(function() {...})` wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

When you wrap a function in `$(document).ready(yourfunction)` (which can be abbreviated as simply `$(yourfunction)`), you're asking jQuery to run the code when the "DOMContentLoaded" event fires. You don't need to do that once the document is ready, and in fact it will prevent your code from working because there will not be another "DOMContentLoaded" event.

All you need is

```
document.arrive("something...", function(){

    document.getElementById('buttonId').click();

})
```

Also note that the library involved is kind-of not necessary at all, and it hasn't been updated in 7 years.

Comment: I tried this option as well, but it doesn't work. This invoking click() event is the problem. I need to use document.arrive, but not able to figure it out how to invoke the click event inside the arrive.

Comment: I tried this option as well, but it doesn't work. This invoking click() event is the problem. I need to use document.arrive, but not able to figure it out how to invoke the click event inside the arrive.